# Getting specific combinations of a character array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm pretty new to making my own algorithms and I got stuck trying to create one for a game I'm creating. The new mechanic is looking for hidden words the player could input in this word scramble game.

#### The Problem

Say I have a character array containing { h, o, t, e, l, b, o, w }. I need to be able to get combinations of the array like so where:

1. Each word is a minimum of 3 letters
2. All letters have to be used else the sequence is invalid.
3. No overlaps

Desired Sequence:

1. hot, elbow
2. hote, lbow
3. hotel, bow
4. hotelbow

The idea is that I can check each sequence for valid words with my database and in the example sequence 1 and 3 are valid.

This is a simple example, there can also be only 1 sequence if the array is less than or equal to 5 characters and there can be 3 valid secret words if the array has lets say 9 characters.

Adding another example where character array containing { s, i, x, c, a, t, r, o, w }:

Desired Sequence:

1. six, cat, row
2. six, catrow
3. sixc, atrow
4. sixca, trow
5. sixcat, row
6. sixcatrow

In this example, only sequence 1 was valid after checking but it was able to make out 3 hidden words that will reward the player.

Comment: I guess you meant seq 1 & 3 are valid (not 1 & 2). I edited it but feel free to revert if you really meant 1 & 2 (and explain why because that doesn't make sense to me). Do the letters have to be in the same order? So `{hob, towel}` is not valid?

Comment: Ah blunder, yes you are correct about the edit. I appreciate the edit. Yes, the letters have to be in the same order so {hob, towel} is not valid.

Comment: Can the same array hold more than 2 words?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make out more than 2 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode for a recursive algorithm for this problem. The basic idea is to break the problem into smaller problems, until you arrive at a base condition that is trivial to solve (in this case, either we used all the letters, or there aren't enough letters left to make a word).

```
// This method "bootstraps" the recursive algorithm
public List<List<String>> findWords(String input) {
    List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    findHiddenWordsRecursive(input, new ArrayList(), results);
    return results;
}

private void findHiddenWordsRecursive(String remainingLetters,
                              List<String> partialResult,
                              List<List<String>> results) {

   If there are no remaining letters, then we used all the letters,
   so add the "partial results" to the results, then return.
 
   If there aren't enough letters remaining to make a word, return.

   Loop over all the possible lengths the next word could have.
   (minimum is 3, max is remainingLetters.length).

   For each possible length N:

       If the first N letters of remaining letters is a dictionary word:
           Copy partialResult into a new list called "nextPartialResult".
           Add the word to nextPartialResult.

           Define a string "nextRemainingLetters" which is the substring
           of remainingLetters starting at index N.

           Call findHiddenWordsRecursive(nextRemainingLetters,
                                         nextPartialResult,
                                         results)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you asked for. For simplicity, I used [deque](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deque-interface-java-example/).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static HashSet<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>(); 
    
    public static void test(Deque<String> deque){
        for (Iterator itr = deque.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) { 
            if(!dictionary.contains(itr.next())) return;
        }
        
        System.out.print("Found combination: ");
        for (Iterator itr = deque.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) { 
            System.out.print(itr.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public static void checkCombinations(String s, int index, Deque<String> deque){
        int rest = s.length() - index;
        if(rest < 6) {
            deque.addLast(s.substring(index, s.length()));
            test(deque);
            deque.removeLast();
            return;
        }
        for(int i = index + 3; i < s.length() - 2; i++){
            deque.addLast(s.substring(index, i));
            checkCombinations(s, i, deque);
            deque.removeLast();
        }
        deque.addLast(s.substring(index, s.length()));
        test(deque);
        deque.removeLast();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deque<String> deque = new LinkedList<String>();
        dictionary.add("hotel"); 
        dictionary.add("bow"); 
        dictionary.add("hot"); 
        dictionary.add("elbow");
        checkCombinations("hotelbow", 0, deque);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Found combination: hot elbow 
Found combination: hotel bow
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems very well suited for a recursive solution. My approach would be to define the recursion as follows:

- Input: character array `s` and limits `start` and `end`. The procedure only considers the portion of `s` from `start` (inclusive) to `end` (exclusive). This will be denoted `s[start,end)`.

1. [Initialization] Define an empty list of sequences called `result`.
2. [Recursive case] If `end-start >= 6`, define a partition index `p` that ranges from `start+3` to `end-3` (inclusive). Recursively collect the sequences for `s[start,p)` in a list `left` and similarly for `s[p,end)` in a list `right`. Append to `result` the Cartesian product of `left` and `right`. (That is, for each sequence `f` that is an element of `left` and for each sequence `g` that is an element of `right`, append the concatenated sequence `f, g` to `result`.)
3. [Base case] If `end-start >= 3`, append the entire word `s[start,end)` to `result`. (Optional: only append `s[start,end)` if it is a valid word.)
4. Return `result`.

To generate the entire list, call this method with the original character array and use 0 for `start` and the length of the array for `end`.

If you are only interested in valid sequences, you could inject the dictionary test into this process. Then in step 3, append `s[start,end)` to `result` only if it passes the test. That way, you only return valid sequences to start with. This would be much more efficient, especially considering that non-valid sequences are usually going to be much more common. Note that this would open the possibility that the method would return an empty list, and hence `left` and/or `right` might be empty in step 2; if that happens, the Cartesian product would also be empty.